# How can I send an array between different scopes?

Tags: javascript, arrays, scope

I created the array in the scope of `$(document).ready(function(){});`

for example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON("data.json", function(json) {

        function Question(q,correactA,array)
        {
            this.question=q;
            this.correct_a=correactA;
            this.answers=array;

        }

        multiQ= new Array();
        for (i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
            var q = json.questions[i].question;
            var corA= json.questions[i].correct_answer;
            var a = json.questions[i].answers;
            var aString = "";
            Object.keys(a).forEach(function (k) {aString += a[k] ;})
            multiQ[i]=new Question(q,corA,aString);
        }

        for (i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
            console.log(multiQ[i]);
        }

    });
});
```

Now I want to send the multiQ array to external var outside the scope.
How can I do it?

Comment: *I created the array in the scope of* — No, you didn't. There is no `var` statement. It's a global already.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23667086/1048572)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Declare

`var multiQ= new Array();`

outside `$(document).ready` function:

```
var multiQ= new Array();
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON("data.json", function(json) {

        function Question(q,correactA,array)
        {
            this.question=q;
            this.correct_a=correactA;
            this.answers=array;

        }

        for (i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
            var q = json.questions[i].question;
            var corA= json.questions[i].correct_answer;
            var a = json.questions[i].answers;
            var aString = "";
            Object.keys(a).forEach(function (k) {aString += a[k] ;})
            multiQ[i]=new Question(q,corA,aString);
        }

        for (i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
            console.log(multiQ[i]);
        }

      });
});
```

Comment: Yes, there's an asynchronous call, so each multiQ[i] won't be populated immediately. In the OP's code, it would be undefined until the callback, in the modification, it would be defined and have 0 length.

Answer (score -1):

It's very ugly, but you could assign a global getter inside the document.ready. For example:

```
var multiQ = new Array();
window.getMultiQ = function() { return multiQ; }
```

Then outside of document ready, you could call "var q = getMultiQ();"

Again, this is very ugly and would lead to unmaintainable code very fast.  Most likely, there's an easier/cleaner way to accomplish what you're trying to do.

Comment: For that, you should use a local `var multiQ`

Comment: Oops, I just assumed he was using "var ..." and copy pasted.